# Odoo SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I am using ODoo 11 and trying to convert odoo 10 module. I am getting SyntaxError: missing : after property id below is the code.

```
    screens.ProductScreenWidget.include({
        click_product: function(product) {
            if (this.pos.config.custom_discount_product_id &&
                this.pos.config.custom_discount_product_id[0] == product.id) {
                this.pos.gui.show_popup('add_discount_product_popup', {
                    product: product,
                    product_options: {}
                });
            } else {
                this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },
    });
```

[image]

Comment: If you mean you're getting that error client-side, from the browser's JavaScript engine, it's not in the code you've shown. That code parses just fine.

Comment: Yes I am getting it client side. Module is not working. I presumed this is why

Comment: Which line is line 73? And is this code from `pos_global_discount.js`?

Comment: Yes its `pos_global_discount.js` 73 is code above `screens.ProductScreenWidget.include({`

Comment: What's around this function call? Sounds like it's within an object initializer but not inside a function.